# How to validate a text field which takes input alpha numeric in Struts 2

Tags: regex, validation, struts2

I am working on Struts2 validator to validate a text field which takes input alpha numeric but my code does not work.

Here is the code:

```xml
<field-validator type="regex">
    <param name="regexExpression">[^[/^(\d)\1+$/g]]</param>
    <message>${getText("bookReq.bookId.err")}</message>
</field-validator>
```

How to parse regular expression in xml? I am getting error here

```
Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 10 [^[/^(\d)\1+$/g]] ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 doesn't validate regex patterns. Instead it validates field value by the valid regex expression. BTW

> `\w`   Matches alphanumeric (same as [a-zA-Z0-9_])

Comment: how can I validate text field of 10 digits with no repated values for example 1111111111 is not valid but 1010101010 is OK

Comment: by using regex like `(10){1,5}`